# Why can't I add an Insights user in roles for my app?

Tags: facebook-insights

On my apps settings > roles, I'm trying to add an Insight user which is one of the add option. However, when I insert the email address and submit it, it's apparently accepted but the new user doesn't appear in the list. I've come back a day later to see if it was a problem of a time delay but get the same results

Answer (score 1):

If the user is not showing up in insights then the user has rejected the invite or the invite was lost to their email spam filters.  Have that user create or login to Facebook add you as a friend and add them by name.

[image]